# Quando usar a palavra function para exportar um componente no React Native

Tags: react-native, componentes

Estou aprendendo React Native a pouco tempo, e como padrão de exportação de componente tenho visto dessa forma:

```
const Componente = () => {

};

export default Componente;
```

porém, me deparei com a seguinte forma de exportação:

```
export default function Componente() {

}
```

a segunda opção me parece mais elegante e direta, gostaria de entender se há alguma diferença
entre usar uma ou outra forma de exportação, e se existe algum caso de uso específico para a segunda opção?

Comment: Ambas vão lhe dar o mesmo resultado. A diferença é mais gosto pessoal ou padrão de escrita dos projetos, e não há diferenças semânticas. Alguns preferem a segunda opção - como você mesmo mencionou - pois gera menos linhas de código. Acho que o que vale mencionar é o problema do `this` em _functions_ normais e _arrow functions_, mas ai é outra questão.

Answer (score -2):

Isso seria mais padronização de código mesmo.

Eu recomendaria usar como const quando tem varios componentes em apenas um arquivo. Quando se usa const, o react cria todas as const antes do render.

```js
const Colors = () => {

};
const Sizes = () => {

};
const Fonts = () => {

};

export {Colors, Sizes,Fonts };
```